# Can two groups be the same if their digraphs/cayley graphs) are different?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-writing, cayley-graphs

Are the groups $\Bbb Z /4\Bbb Z$ of integers$\mod 4$ (addition) and the set of all iterated compositions of $a$ and $b$ where $a,b$: $\Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R^2$ be defined by $a(x,y)=(-x,y)$ and $b(x,y)=(x,-y)$ for all $(x,y)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ the same? I created digraphs for both groups and they are different. I believe that means they are not the same but I don't know why?

Comment: Please use LaTeX.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by the 'digraph' of the group? Note that a Cayley graph is created (generally) not just from a group but from a specific set of generators of that group.

Comment: Yes, different groups cannot have the same Cayley graph. Every group can be reconstructed uniquely from its Cayley graph. The group you are refering to is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ and that is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: n.b.: different groups will have different Cayley graphs, but having two Cayley graphs that are different does _not_ necessarily imply that the groups which generated them are different.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. The group you are refering to is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$. The isomorphism is given by $a\mapsto (1,0)$, $b\mapsto (0, 1)$. And $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ **is not** isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

As for Cayley graphs: the group $G$ can be recovered uniquely from the Cayley graph $\Gamma(G, S)$. See wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph#Characterization

Thus different groups cannot give "the same" (i.e. isomorphic) Cayley graph.

Comment: This is wrong, or at least very misleading. Non-isomorphic groups can definitely have isomorphic (unlabelled) Cayley graphs. For example, the complete graph is a Cayley graph on every group with cardinality equal to its order.

Comment: Of course, if the graph is given together with vertex and directed edge labels, then you already have the group by definition, but this is not the right context for Sabidussi's Theorem, which tells you how to recover the group and connection set from an unlabelled graph (although not uniquely). That section on Wikipedia is poorly written. For example, it claims to recover $G$ and $S$ from the graph, but then it uses $G$ in the recovery, so in fact it is explaining how to recover $S$ from the graph together with $G$.

Comment: Finally, note that this part of the answer is not actually relevant to the question, which asks about different digraphs for a given group, not different groups for a given graph.